# Win32: Modeless dialog going behind parent if created before showing the parent

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to debug an strange behavior in a large application: If I create child modeless dialogs after the parent window is shown, they are kept above their parent even if the parent is activated. However, if I create them before the parent window is shown (note that the parent has been created, but not yet shown), then the parent doesn't seem to honor the childs in zorder... child dialogs get behind the parent if you click the parent for activating it.

What causes could trigger this behavior? Note that it's only a matter of whether dialogs are created before or after calling ShowWindow() on the parent.

Comment: You need to make the modeless dialog be owned by what you term the parent window

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason why you don't need to make it explicitly owned if it's created after the parent has been shown?

Comment: We can't see you code, and I don't want to speculate

Comment: It is **always** required to pass an owner if a dialog is supposed to be in front of that owner.